# Kotlin - use compiled regex inside init block throws null pointer exception

Tags: kotlin

I have the following data class in Kotlin

```
data class AppInfoBO constructor(
        val appVersion: String
) {
    val majorVersion: Int?
    val minorVersion: Int?
    init {
        val matches = majorVersionRegex.find(appVersion)
        if (matches != null) {
            majorVersion = matches.groups[1]?.value?.toInt()
            minorVersion = matches.groups[2]?.value?.toInt()
        } else {
            majorVersion = null
            minorVersion = null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val UNKNOWN = AppInfoBO("UNKNOWN")

        @JvmStatic
        val majorVersionRegex = Regex("""(\d+)\.(\d+)\.""")
    }
```

When I try to run this it complains that the `majorVersionRegex` inside the companion object is null.

If I move the `majorVersionRegex` inside a kotlin object, it works fine.

```
    private object RegexHolder {
        val majorVersionRegex = Regex("""(\d+)\.(\d+)\.""")
    }
```

I'm trying to make the `majorVersionRegex` a static variable so the regex doesn't need to be compiled over and over again.

Is there a better approach for this?  This really feels like a hack.

Comment: I thought this looked fine at first, and as expected I am [unable to reproduce this](https://ideone.com/KNwSfm) while testing. Maybe more details would help? How are you creating an instance of this data class?

Comment: In case you're trying to initialize a constant `AppInfoBO` inside the companion object and before the regex is declared, there will be a NPE. Not sure if that's your case here, but you can just move the declaration after the regex.

Comment: @Nicolas you nailed it!!  Very impressive considering that my original post omitted that!!  If you want to write up an answer I'll happily give you credit!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that that you're trying to initialize a status `val UNKNOWN = AppInfoBO("UNKNOWN")` before you define `majorVersionRegex`.

The fix is to move `majorVersionRegex` above `UNKNOWN`.

```
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val majorVersionRegex = Regex("""(\d+)\.(\d+)\.""")

        @JvmField
        val UNKNOWN = AppInfoBO("UNKNOWN")
    }
```